# rotational symmetry on a circle

Tags: geometry, rotations

I've heard that rotational symmetry is where a figure is rotated a bit before it looks the same. in that case, what rotational symmetry is there on a circle? is there none, or is there infinite, or is it something else?

Comment: Rotating a circle through any angle leaves it unchanged. The rotational symmetry group of a circle is infinite.

Comment: if you have a circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$, then there exists a Lie group of invariance of the circle $O(2)$, under the transformation of this symmetry group the circle is mapped onto itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, there is an infinite order of rotation.

That is because the the centroid, the centre, has the same distance to any point on the circumference.

Common sense: it cannot be zero as there is more than no order of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$, then there exists a Lie group of invariance of the circle $O(2)$, under the transformation of this symmetry group the circle is mapped onto itself i.e. remains invariant, so we say there is the rotational symmetry. More concretely, by taking the $2\times2$ irreducible representation of $o(2)$
$$R=\Big\{\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}\Big\}\cup\Big\{\begin{bmatrix}
-\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}\Big\}\in{o(2)}
$$
The transformation 
$$r\rightarrow{r'}=Rr$$
where $r=[x, y]$. leaves the equation $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ invariant

Comment: This is a bit nasty thinking in the spirit of Klein, however it is really practical!

Comment: And yet does not answer the OP.