# using a complex dilation on a figure

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I know that a dilation increases or decreases a figure, and a negative amount inverts it through a point, but what about an imaginary dilation? is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. Yes, with the correct interpretation it is indeed possible. That interpretation happens in the complex number plane.

There multiplication by a positive real number is a dilation. Multiplication by $-1$ is an inversion.

Multiplication by an arbitrary complex number is a rotation and a dilation. You can see the amounts by writing the number in polar form.

The two examples you started with are special cases, the first when the angle is $0$, the second when the stretch is $1$ and the angle is $\pi$ (half a circle). Multiplication by $i$ is a turn through a quarter of a circle.

PS This question is similar to your other one, at [rotational symmetry on a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2219435/rotational-symmetry-on-a-circle) .

Comment: Oh, really? this is pretty useful.